# Get Actual values from C# redis scan

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to get actual values matched after a redis scan using stackexchange.redis in C#.
During debugging, it returns an object of type {StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ScanIterator<StackExchange.Redis.RedisValue>}.

how do I get the actual values matched by the scan?

var matches = redisDB.SetScan("ssnit", $"{identifier}*", cursor: 0);

Comment: What have you tried?  SetScan returns an IEnumerable<RedisValue>, so you could just try iterating through "matches".

Comment: during debugging, it returns an object of type {StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ScanIterator<StackExchange.Redis.RedisValue>}